# Ruby on Rails + Passenger unable to load cached assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, passenger

I just installed passenger and I believe I got it working, but now my rails application seems to be unable to load cached assets. When attempting to load a page I get this message:

> ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory - /home/glawson/vidStream/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets%2Ff1663d34d4b6003379113df98f1433a520130421-27670-18ux0pw.lock):

```
2: <html>
3: <head>
4:   <title>VidStream</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8:
```

> app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___4187138815701226714_20468720'

This happens when I try to run my webapp with passenger or in development with rails server. I'm a little fuzzy on what the error even means other than it can't find a file that it's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In production mode you need to precompile the asset directory using

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Then only it will work. Because by default for prod asset precompile is enabled.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, I've tried precompiling the assets, and I've tried running in development mode, but both ways I still get the same error.